# What is the SEPA optional category?

Tags: online-banking, european-union, wire-transfer, sepa

When I'm writing a wire transfer (both with my personal and with my company's accounts), my bank allows me to enter "optional SEPA fields", most of them look redundant or useless, but one is a bit puzzling: the category.

Here it is (in Italian):

[image: SEPA categories]

While the short description is quite clear, it's also a bit narrow and there are many cases where I'm not really sure what should I enter, so I usually just leave it empty.

Is there a more detailed list about that?